# Why does this loop infinitely execute if the condition for the for loop is above 2?

Tags: java

```
public class Proof {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            do {
                if (x == 0) {
                    x = x * 3 + 1;
                } else if (x % 2 != 0) {
                    x = x * 3 + 1;
                } else if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    x /= 2;
                }
                System.out.println(x);
            } while (x != 1);

            System.out.println("DONE!!!!!!");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

To test this issue just change `x < 3` to `2` and it works fine. Then change it back to `3` and it doesn't work. I'm just a new programmer but I'm confused about this.

Comment: Try stepping through it with a debugger and look at the values of `x` for each iteration.

Comment: Your can exit your `do{..}while(x!=1);` loop only when `x` is `1`.  
But since that `x` is also used in outer loop (`for`) as its continue condition `x<3` and `2<3` (2 because of x++ is executed at end of that for loop) is true, it starts another iteration.

Answer (score 1):

So, when x == 1, you go through the do while loop and eventually the value goes back to 1, you exit and then you iterate the for loop to 2... That would exit the for loop when you change is to x < 2.

When x < 3, what happens? X goes through the do while loop just like before, but you don't exit the for loop at 2, you actually go back into the do while loop. But when do you exit the do while loop??? Only when x == 1... so then what happens to your for loop? It iterates x to..... 2 again. And you are back in your do while loop. Forever!

As Casey said, the debugger will show you this and is incredibly useful. Good luck going forward!

Answer (score 1):

Once your `for` loop reaches it's second iteration (`x = 2`), your `do while` loop will set it back to `1` (`x /= 2`), and your `for` loop increments it back to `2` (`x++`), causing the process to repeat infinitely.

Here's a visual:

[image: Infinite Loop]

Comment: How did you create that nice visual?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I used the [LICEcap screen capture tool](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Answer (score 0):

- x is initially equal to **1**.
- Go through the first `else if` condition, x is increased to **4**.
- x != 1 at this point; iterate in the `while` loop again, and go through the second `else if` condition. x is divided by 2 and is therefore equal to **2**.
- When equal to 2, x%2 ==0 is true, x is divided by 2 again and goes down to **1**.
- The `while` loop is exited as x is equal to **1**.
- Back to the for loop, x is increased to **2**, and you go back through the second `else if` condition.

You're back to the fourth step, thus reaching a cycle in the calculation and having the infinite loop execution you described.

Comment: Almost. You skipped  `x++` at the end of `for` loop. But idea is right.

Comment: @Pyves Uh. I dont know how to format properly on this website so here is a pastebin link with the working code http://pastebin.com/0iUrjT1a